# Постраничный вывод данных с БД Joomla

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, joomla, php7, joomla3

С БД Joomla получаю данные

```
$db = Factory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$db->setQuery($query);
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('number1', 'name1', 'question1')))
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__mytable'))
    ->order($db->quoteName('id') . ' DESC')
$results = $db->loadAssocList();?>
```

и вывожу их. Но как вывести например по 10 на странице не знаю. Так выводится все что в таблице.

````
<thead><tr>
<th>Номер</th>
<th>Название</th>
<th>примечание</th>
</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<?php
foreach ($results as $row) {    
     echo '<td>' . $row['number1'] . '</td><td>' . $row['name1'] . '</td><td>' . $row['question1'] . '</td><tr>';   
}?>
 </tr> 
</tbody> 
</table>```
````

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768647/joomla-database-how-to-use-limit-in-getquery

Comment: Там о том как установить лимит на вывод. Я это пробовал ```$query->setLimit(10); ``` Просто выводит 10 записей. А остальные как?

Comment: ajax-ом обратиться к серверу, запросить «следующую страницу», на бэке сделать тот же запрос к БД, указав номер страницы (offset)

Answer (score 0):

Дошел до получения количества страниц. А дальше никак.

````
$ShowRows = 10; // количество записей на странице
/*получаем количество записей в таблице*/
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true)
->select($db->quoteName(array('id')))
->from($db->quoteName('#__mytable'));
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->execute();
$num_rows = $db->getNumRows();
$result = $db->loadRowList();
?>

<?php
$get_p_num = ceil($num_rows/$ShowRows); // узнаем необходимое количество страниц (округляем в большую сторону ceil)
?>```
````